# Acess denied while trying to open file with python

Tags: python

I'm in this `1.py` file, and I would like to execute the `main.py` at some point. I tried using:

```
import os
os.chdir("/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/seila")
os.system("/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects3/seila/main.py")
```

But the result indicated that the access was denied.

How can I solve this?

Comment: if you are going to import this 'main.py' instead of using os you can just do import main

Comment: The path makes it look like the script is in an android device, are you trying to run the script on the device from a computer or something like that? please give as much information as you can about the problem.

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem and what steps you have performed to solve till now.

Comment: I am using qpython, an Android app

Answer (score 0):

I Just user the "import" and It worked.
Thank you all for the Help.